# JQuery .extend() and Javascript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to incorporate some of my Java objects into my dynamic document through the use of JQuery (1.7.1 or 2.2.3). To do so, I thought of using the JQuery `.extend()` function in order to augment a basic JQuery object that I then append to my document.

I think there is something wrong in my approach (that I corrected as presented at the end of the question), but I have found a misleading behavior that I could not explain and make my code work partly when I thought it should totally work or not at all.

The overall purpose of my code is to add a "button" element (in a `<div>` section) in the code so as to apply some specific treatment when this element is clicked as well as doing some other treatment on it. Basically, I want my "button" JQuery object to behave like the `Button` JavaScript object/class that I've created (as I would expect with a object oriented approach).

Here is the simplified code for the `Button` object:

```
function Button( myState )
{
    this.setState(myState);
}
Button.prototype.printState = function()
{
    console.log( this.state );
}
Button.prototype.setState = function(myState)
{
    this.state = myState;
}
```

Here is the JQuery+Button base code that creates the object:

```
// Create a "JQuery+Button" object
function createButton()
{
    var result = $("<a href='#' id='button'></a>");
    result.extend( new Button(false) ); // Can also be done with result = $.extend( result, new Button(false) );
    result.append( "clickable button" ); // A dummy button text, see below

    result.printState(); // OK: print "false"
    return result;
}
```

And here is the "creation+action" part of the code:

```
function associateButtons()
{
    var myButton = createButton();

    // Add an action on click => Works "as excepted" => print the state when the button will be clicked
    myButton.on( "click", myButton, function(event) {
        console.log("click inner HTML:" + event.data.html()); // OK: print the JQuery associated HTML
        event.data.printState(); // OK: call the associated function
    });


    $( "#buttons_container" ).append( myButton ); // Add the button to the page at the specified place
    $( "#buttons_container" ).append( myButton.clone() ); // Add the same button a second time, but won't have the "onclick" bind

    // Do an action no each button => Does not work! => The function is undefined
    $( "#buttons_container #button" ).each( function(index,element) {
        console.log("each inner HTML:" + $(element).html()); // OK: print the JQuery associated HTML, same as above ; also works with $(this)
        $(element).printState(); // FAIL: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"
    });
}
```

Now, run the test :

```
associateButtons();
```

So I was wondering why does the "event" method work while the "each" method does not? I'm doubtful on the type of the element passed by the event manager (which is clearly an object encapsulating a JQuery+Button object through the structure `event.data`) being different from the element passed by the "each manager" (which is not the JQuery+Button object but a "simple" JQuery object).

I've managed to find workaround but encapsulating the Button in the JQuery appended through the `.data()` function:

```
// Create a "JQuery+Button" object
function createButton()
{
    var result = $("<a href='#' id='button'></a>");
    result.data( "button", new Button(false) );
    result.append( "clickable button" ); // A dummy button text, see below

    result.data("button").printState(); // OK: print "false"
    return result;
}
```

And working with that object in the event (`event.data.data("button")`) and the "each" (`$(element).data("button")`), this works well.

However, it is not as "Object Oriented" as I would like it to be by the definition of my ideal "JQuery+Button" object.

Is there a way to achieve it, am I missing something in the "each" treatment?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) You are appending several buttons with the same `id` (`"button"`) to the same HTML document, which is evil.

2) When you do `result.extend( new Button(false) );`, you only add properties to the `result` object, **not** to the HTML element, nor, obviously, the jQuery object returned by `$( "#buttons_container #button" )`,  nor the jQuery objects in the jQuery `forEach` loop.

EDIT:

When you do this:

```
var myButton = createButton();
myButton.on( "click", myButton, function(event) { (...) }
```

You are adding a click event handler to the object returned by the `createButton` function, which **is** extended, so you have access to the printState property on it.

But when you do

```
$( "#buttons_container #button" ).each( function(index,element) {
  console.log("each inner HTML:" + $(element).html());
  $(element).printState();
});
```

`$(element)` is a basic jQuery object, which **is not** extended, so there is no `printState` property on it.

Moreover, I think you should take a look at the [jQuery plugin resources](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link!

1) My bad, of course ids have to be unique, according to the standard.

2) Yes. However, I would expect the operation to **not work at all** or **work completely**. However, it does *work* for the `click` event (through the `event.data` instance) and *does not work* when traversing the tree.

I guess that the created event object is done by the JQuery lib and somewhere the `JQuery+Button` object has been tracked so that it is usable when the event is triggered.
So there must be a way to get this `JQuery+Button` obj. elsewhere, somehow.

Comment: I added more explanation. I'm hoping it would help you understand better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is much clearier now ;)